# Can Mockito 3.6.0 completely replace PowerMockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Our team recently found out that Mockito now supports mocking static methods (https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#48) which was one of the main reason for using PowerMock in our unit tests.
Since we have had issues with PowerMock 2.0 regarding performance, we want to move to using Mockito 3.6.0 for everything.

We do however use other PowerMock methods like *verifyPrivate, suppress, replace, etc.*.
Has anyone written or knows of any guide for migrating unit tests from PowerMock to Mockito 3.6.0 ?

Comment: What `PowerMock` can do, `Mockito` can not, at least there is a subset of features that is simply not possible. like : `SuppressStaticInitializationFor` or `verifyPrivate` that you mention. So there is no "guide".